# Creating a query using eloquent in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Ok, so I'm needing to create a query below in eloquent or Laravel in some matter. I'm just not sure how I would create something like this:

```
select * from 
(select * from Bulk 
  where Login = 'moga' and ApptDate='2015-02-25' 
  order by FormatTime asc) as A
group by Name
```

This query will run just fine as a raw query in the database, I'm just not sure how I would pull this query off using query helper or eloquent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either Eloquent or Query Builder. Here's an example with the Query Builder:

```
DB::table(DB::raw('(select * from Bulk where Login = "moga" and ApptDate="2015-02-25" order by FormatTime asc) as A'))
    ->groupBy('Name')
    ->get();
```

With Eloquent you'd use `ModelName::from()` instead of `DB::table()`. But keeping in mind that `DB::raw` does not escape variable values inserted into the query string, you could build the nested query using the builder as well, to make sure you're not vulnerable to SQL injection:

```
$from = DB::table('Bulk')
    ->where('Login', $login)
    ->where('ApptDate', $date)
    ->orderBy('FormatTime')
    ->toSql();

DB::table(DB::raw('(' . $from  . ') A'))->groupBy('Name')->toSql();
```